# Python - How to detect a file of given type in a folder

Tags: python, excel, directory, operating-system

I want to use Python to move .xlsx files if they are in a certain folder.
Is there a generic rule for this?

What I am looking for is basically code for this:

if there is a file that is an excel document in /user/documents/folder:
   move it to trash.

I'm happy with the shutil.move bit but what can I use to classify .xlsx files as a group?

Comment: look up `glob.glob("*.xlsx")`

Comment: You can also use `pathlib.Path.match` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.match

Comment: I would use `os.listdir()` and `os.remove()` to handle this!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone. This turned out to be the easiest way of doing this

```
import os

folder = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\somefolder')
for item in folder:
    if item.endswith('.xlsx') == True:
        print ('excel folder is in this folder')
```

I can then add a shutil.move function with ""if item.endswith('xlsx') == True""
to move the file elsewhere. 
Thanks for the support I.Renk and others :)